# Confused about Dynamic programming Matrix problem

Tags: algorithm

I am learning this and I understand the Distance graph and the sequence graph and how to come up with the paths of the vertices.  I am a bit confused on this question though. [image: Algorithm Question]

Comment: Can you give some context information? For example how is the input graph? (I imagine directed because the matrix isn't symmetric, and weighted). What does 0 mean? (There exist a path from of weight 0 or there isn't any path)

Comment: That is my confusion too cause this is it....this is the question....its saying that if you did the algorithm....this is what is passed back to you....and to now read it and and answer A and B....that why I wasnt really sure where to go from here

Comment: I think means no path

Comment: @Jennifer, if a 0 means "no path", then the table shows there is no path from v1 to v8 (there is a zero there). Yet there is apparently a path from v1 to v2 (cost = 7) and also from v2 to v8 (cost = 1), so we can go from v1 to v8 via v2. This is conflicting information.

Comment: @Jennifer, if a 0 means "zero" cost, there is *also* a conflict, because then we can go from v1 to v7 at zero cost, and from v7 to v5 at zero cost, so there is a way to go with zero cost from v1 to v5, but in the table it shows a cost of 7. So this is also conflicting. We need the applicable definition of "path matrix" that does not lead to such contradictions.